# Convert Circle to Polyline

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, polyline

I have **svg circle** like:

```
<circle stroke-width="10px" cx="317.5" cy="108.5" r="52.71147882577384"></circle>
```

We can treat it as some point with defined radius.

**Question:** how to draw polyline(set of small lines) to reproduce this circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to draw a polygon with many sides. 
In the next example the vertices of the polygon are at .1 radians from each others. Depending on the size of the circle you may need to use a smaller value,

```js
let r = 52.71;// the radius of the circle
let cx = 317.5;// the x coord of the center of the circle
let cy = 108.5;// the y coord of the center of the circle
let points = "";// the points for the polyline

for (let a = 0; a <= 2*Math.PI; a+=.1) {
  let x = cx + r * Math.cos(a);
  let y = cy + r * Math.sin(a);
  points += `${x}, ${y} `;
}
// close the path
//if you are using polygon instead of polyline you may skip this line
points += `${cx + r}, ${cy} `;
// set the atribute points for the polyline
poly.setAttributeNS(null, "points", points)
```

```css
svg{border: solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox ="260 50 115 115" width="200">
  <circle id="c" cx="317.5" cy="108.5" r="52.71" fill="gold"></circle>
  <polyline id="poly" points="" stroke="red" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And number of segments I will calculate using const cos = (radius - precision) / radius; const numberOfSegments = Math.PI * 2 / Math.acos(cos). To make it more adaptive then just 0.1

Answer (score 1):

```js
const NUM_VERTICES = 30;
const DELTA_THETA = 2 * Math.PI / NUM_VERTICES;

function getVertices(options) {
  const { cx, cy, r } = options;
  
  function getParametricCoordinates(t) {
    return [
      r * Math.cos(t) + cx,
      r * Math.sin(t) + cy,
    ];
  }
  
  const vertices = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= NUM_VERTICES; i++) {
    const t = i * DELTA_THETA;
    const vertex = getParametricCoordinates(t);
    vertices.push(vertex);
  }
  return vertices;
}

const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const polyline = document.getElementById('polyline');
const vertices = getVertices({ cx: 317.5, cy: 108.5, r: 52.71147882577384 } );
vertices.forEach(vertex => {
  const point = svg.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = vertex[0];
  point.y = vertex[1];
  polyline.points.appendItem(point);
});
```

```html
<svg width="450" height="250" id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <polyline id="polyline" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is also a brilliant answer. Unfortunately I can't set both answers as a solution